# JQuery Get Selected Item from List Box and split by comma

Tags: jquery, html, loops

Can anyone offer more help on this I have the code setup on jsfiddle at...

http://jsfiddle.net/justinerswell/feDTU/

I need to get the last item in the substr and work backwards to populate the fields I need.

Thanks

*Original Question*

Hi I have a list box returned on a page with multiple result which are being parsed in as a string into the value...

```
<option value="1 Corn Exchange, The Strand, RYE, East Sussex, TN31 7DB, UNITED KINGDOM">
```

Using JQuery I need to do a couple of things..

1. Get Selected Value
2. Split Value of Selected Item by Comma's
3. Loop through in revers and set a variable for each item i.e country: United Kingdom Postcode:TN31 7DB etc

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: This is a terrible approach.  You should definitely reconsider whatever lead you to it, especially as there is no hard tie between each comma value and its label.  Why can't you just output each item from the start into separate `option` items?

Comment: good suggestion @adam-terlson however no doing its a result from a web service this is what I have :(

Comment: Sounds like your web service needs changing.  I feel very sorry for whomever has to support your code in the future, even if it might be you.

Comment: what should I be asking of the web service provider? I am only working with what i am getting given. thanks for the pity ;)

Comment: Your web service should return the data and meta-data necessary to process it and know what each bit of information is.  In this case, it could return JSON that looks like this:  `{ country: 'UNITED KINGDOM', postcode: 'TN31 7DB' ... }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you want to fetch the data on click or submit?

```
    $('select').click( function() {

        var selected = $(this).find(':selected').text();

        var substr = selected.split(',');
        var product = substr[0];
        var city = substr[1];
        var postcode = substr[2];
        var country = substr[3];

        //DO SOMETHING WITH IT??
    });
```

But its not a very good idea, considering your "data" structure can't change (ie. missing fields and so on) - since it will break on the indexes....

Comment: I want the user to select the row they want then click a button and return the data to a parent form i thought window,opener for that bit thanks for the answer looks good i will test it @marco-johannesen

Comment: If you need more help, just paste some of your HTML :)

Comment: I have create a jsfiddle as there is a lot of code currently this loops forward and i need to loop in reverse as there maybe 5 elements rather than 6 http://jsfiddle.net/justinerswell/3HKgQ/1/

Answer (score 5):

jquery has a selector for selected value.

so use

```
var selectedValue = $('#myselect option:selected').val();
```

then split on space

```
var table = selectedValue.split(',');
```

and loop on your table

```
for(i = 0 ; i < table.length; i++) {
    // dosomething with table[i]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

suppose if you are use Html Listbox than try this

```
 <select id="Select1" size="4" multiple="multiple" onchange="Check(this);">
 <option value="1">item 1</option>
 <option value="2">item 2</option>
 <option value="3">item 3</option>
 <option value="4">item 4</option>
 <option value="0">All</option>
</select>
```

javascript

```
 function Check(selectObject)
  {
   var items = new Array();
   for (var i = 0, j = selectObject.options.length; i < j; i++)
   {
       if (selectObject.options[i].selected)
       {
           items.push(selectObject.options[i].value);
       }
   }
   // selectObject.id holds the "id"
   var itemsToString = items.toString();
   alert(itemsToString);
   //split and get values.
   var s = itemsToString.split(',');
   for(var k=0; k<s.length; k++)
      {
           alert(s[k]);
      }

  }
```

Hops its helps

Answer (score 3):

Try **$.map()** to get all selected items in list

```
var selectedValues = $.map($('#ddlList option:selected'), function (element) {
        return element.value;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple, call this function onchange() event of  dropdown listbox .

function FuncFilter() {

```
     var selectedText = $("#DrpDatefilter").find(':selected').text();
     alert(selectedText );

    **Or** 
     var selectedValue = $("#DrpDatefilter").find(':selected').val();
     alert(selectedValue );

 }
```